# I want to create a .class file that contains all my functions.I can't compile it. what should i import?

Tags: java

```
class A
{
    public static int Factorial(int n)
    {
        return (n*Factorial(n-1));
        system.out.println("The Factorial of "+n+" is "+(n*Factorial(n-1)));
    }
}
```

I want to create a .class file that contains all my functions.I can't compile it. what should i import?

Comment: `system` -> `System`.

Comment: @tkausl Doesn't fix much, since the statement is unreachable.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You will also never see the print because the return comes before that. It's also recursive which will make this a loop. And please use lower case for method names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class A {

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) { // stop recursion
            return 1;
        }
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
        /**
        * The code here will be ignored
        */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial(n));
    }

}
```

Comment: Best style, though the error should have been explained: **After the return statement, the statement with System.out.println is not reachable, and the compiler assumes this to be an error.**

Comment: @JoopEggen The compiler or the OP?

Comment: @RashadSaleh unreachable statements (like after `return` or `break`) are not allowed in java. So the java compiler marks them as erroneous. The OP obviously assumed `return` to specify the result, and be able to continue by printing something.